# How to handle page event in the Detail View

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Using C#

Table

```
ID Name

001 Raja
002 Ramu
003 Ravi
004 Sajuee
```

Detail View Code:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" Height="50px" Width="125px" AllowPaging="True" EnableViewState="False">
<Fields>  
<asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product" SortExpression="ProductName" />  <asp:BoundField DataField="vehiclename" HeaderText="Category" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="vehiclename" />  <asp:BoundField DataField="platecode" HeaderText="Supplier" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="platecode" />  <asp:BoundField DataField="inscom" HeaderText="Qty/Unit" SortExpression="inscom" />  <asp:BoundField DataField="inedate" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="inedate" />   </Fields> 
</asp:DetailsView>
```

When i run the code, Details View is Displaying First ID, First Name from the table.

Detail View Displaying like this

```
ID 001
Name Raja

Link: 1 2 3 4
```

But when i click the link2 it showing errors as "The DetailsView 'DetailsView1' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled."

Details View is not displaying all the data.

How to solve this issue.

Need C# code Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't using a DataSource control (like SQLDataSource), you have to handle the PageIndexChanging event, and rebind the datasource with the underlying data.  Otherwise, the data source control handles all those events for you.

HTH.